# How to share PDF file with Evernote in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, evernote

I want to share PDF file with Evernote in iOS application.

Note: I have found the code of Evernote login from Evernote official website but didn't get any reference of sharing PDF from anywhere.

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution of my above question :

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf-sample" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *pdfFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
ENResource * resource = [[ENResource alloc] initWithData:pdfFileData mimeType:@"application/pdf" filename:@"pdf-sample.pdf"];
ENNote * note = [[ENNote alloc] init];
note.title = @"Costsfirst PDF file";
[note addResource:resource];
[[ENSession sharedSession] uploadNote:note notebook:nil completion:^(ENNoteRef *noteRef, NSError *uploadNoteError) {
    NSString * message = nil;
    if (noteRef) {
        message = @"Pdf uploaded!";
    } else {
        message = @"Failed to upload.";
    }
}];
```

Above code is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand your question then, to share PDF with Evernote from your iOS app, can be achieved via **UIActivityViewController**.

try this:

```
NSData *pdfFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFilePath];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", pdfFileData] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

--- OR ---

```
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourPdfFileName" ofType:@"pdf"];   
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str]] applicationActivities:nil];
```

With the code above, You could scroll over on UIActivityViewController’s share section, and use other custom share extensions like **Evernote**.

You didn’t have to do a thing.  As a user, just click the more button to show the ones you want in the share sheet.  As a developer, you don’t have to do anything to your UIActivityViewController to show custom Share and Action Extensions.

Hope this may help you.

Regarding Evernote cloud sdk for iOS:
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Getting_Started.md
This document covers getting set up with the Evernote Cloud SDK for iOS, some quick examples, and some discussion of the primary classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have aldeady gone through this. I want to know about only pdf sharing.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please let me know if that helps or not.

Comment: thanks for your effort but this is not my requirement, I want to share PDF file in back ground no user interaction is required in this case.